Confusion regarding partial derivatives as basis vectors
In differential geometry we may define as basis vectors the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$. The question that I have is that if we choose these as basis vectors how can we calculate the inner product of them and hence how can we find the value of the corresponding element of the metric tensor $g_{ij}=\left\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} \right\rangle$. I am also wondering whether the classical euclidian vectors in 3 dimensions are equivalent to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$.
Also the other source of confusion that I have is that we say that those derivatives-vectors have as covectors the differentials $dx^i$. From what I have understood a covector acts on a vector giving a scalar. In what exact manner does the differential act on the partial derivative in order to give the scalar? (I'm particularly interested in this due to its applications in physics, so I'd appreciate explanations that avoid any overly complex mathematics.)

Given just a smooth manifold, you cannot calculate the metric tensor, the metric tensor s a different object that you put on your smooth manifold.

@ArcticChar Thanks for the comment, it was helpful. So if we have the metric tensor, each component is equal to the inner product of the corresponding partial derivatives. But how can we define the inner product of two derivatives? It seems that it doesn't make sense

Why not? Given two functions $ f, g: U\to \mathbb R$, we can define an inner product by integration: $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_U fg dx$. Given any finite dimensional vector space you can define an inner product on it.

@ArcticChar But in your case we have functions, not derivatives

That's not the point, it is not about the objects, as long as they form a vector space, one can define an inner product on it. Whether or not it is the vector space of functions or derivations, it does not matter.

Let me use $\partial_i$ for $\partial/\partial x^i$ for brevity.
The action of the covector $dx^i$ on the vector $\partial_j$ is defined as $dx^i(\partial_j)=\partial_j x^i=\delta^i_j$. This part is independent of what metric is chosen on the manifold.
In physics, the metric is usually written as $ds^2 = g_{ij} dx^i dx^j$, where $dx^i dx^j = dx^i \otimes dx^j$. That is, the metric is a rank-2 cotensor that takes a rank-2 tensor and spits out a number. In particular, the action of the metric on the tensor product of two vectors $v=v^i \partial_i$ and $w=w^i\partial_i$ is $ds^2(v\otimes w) =g_{ij} v^k w^l dx^i(\partial_k) dx^j(\partial_l) = g_{ij} v^i w^j$. Since the metric is symmetric and positive definite (on a Riemannian manifold), this quantity can be used to define an inner product at every point in the manifold.
And you are right that in the 3-dimensional Euclidean space, the standard basis corresponds to $\partial_x, \partial_y, \partial_z$.
